# torch write video throws IndexError

Tags: torchvision

torchvision write_video throws this error without any information for all videos in the dataset.

```
  write_video(filename=str(output_path), video_array=clip_video, fps=video_fps, audio_array=clip_audio, audio_fps=audio_fps, audio_codec='aac')
  File "/home/team/miniconda3/envs/gm_torch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/io/video.py", line 117, in write_video
    audio_sample_fmt = container.streams.audio[0].format.name
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the line at File "/home/team/miniconda3/envs/gm_torch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/io/video.py", line 117, in write_video:

```
audio_sample_fmt = container.streams.audio[0].format.name
```

with:

```
audio_sample_fmt = "s16p"
```

"s16p" works but "s16" does not.

container.streams.audio is an empty tuple this makes sense because it is empty file created from scratch. This code worked before i changed my ubuntu version and from source installation to conda installation of torchvision. I don't what is causing this.

Comment: for me this yields a further error regarding numpy array shape: 
    frame = av.AudioFrame.from_ndarray(audio_array, format=audio_sample_fmt, layout=audio_layout)
  File "av\audio\frame.pyx", line 126, in av.audio.frame.AudioFrame.from_ndarray
  File "av\utils.pyx", line 80, in av.utils.check_ndarray_shape

Comment: try also `audio_sample_fmt = 'fltp'`, it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that line `audio_sample_fmt = container.streams.audio[0].format.name`
`len(container.streams.audio)==0` is in fact true.
Thus the indexerror.

In order to fix the issue, they should do `audio_sample_fmt = a_stream.format.name` instead.